# Linq to sql update does now work

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I'm trying to update some data from my database by using linq. All of the other codes that i write in the following method work as i expected but the update code that at the marked line does not work. No changes in the database. I have debugged it and i'am getting the values that i expected from user. The only problem is the change that i expect in the database. What can be the problem ?

```
    private void addToCart()
    {
        FixbayDBDataContext db = new FixbayDBDataContext();

        if (Session["CustomerAuthentication"] != null)
        {
            CartTbl cartTbl = new CartTbl();
            CartShoeTbl csTbl = new CartShoeTbl();

            int cusID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["CustomerAuthentication"]);
            int shoeID = Convert.ToInt32(sizeDdl.Text);


            var idQuery = from c in db.CartTbls.AsQueryable()
                          where c.CustomerID == cusID
                          select new{c.CartID,c.CustomerID};


            var shoeQuery = from s in db.ShoeTbls.AsQueryable()
                            join m in db.ShoeModelTbls on s.ModelID equals m.ModelID
                            where s.ShoeID == shoeID
                            select new { s.ShoeID, m.Price };

            int quantity = Convert.ToInt32(quantityDdl.Text);
            double shoePrice = (double)shoeQuery.First().Price;
            double totalPrice = quantity * shoePrice;
            //int shoeID = (int)shoeQuery.First().ShoeID;
            //int lastShoeID = 0;

            if (idQuery.Any())
            {
                int cartID = (int)idQuery.FirstOrDefault().CartID;
                var cartShoeQuery = from ca in db.CartShoeTbls.AsQueryable()
                                    where ca.CartID == cartID && ca.ShoeID == shoeID
                                    select ca;

                if (cartShoeQuery.Any())
                {
                    csTbl.Quantity += Convert.ToInt32(quantityDdl.Text);
                    db.SubmitChanges();
                }
                else
                {
                    var cartQuery = from ca in db.CartTbls.AsQueryable()
                                    where ca.CustomerID == cusID
                                    select new { ca.CartID, ca.TotalPrice };

                    double currentTotal = (double)cartQuery.FirstOrDefault().TotalPrice;
                    currentTotal = currentTotal + totalPrice;

                    cartTbl.TotalPrice = currentTotal;  //UPDATE LINE
                db.SubmitChanges();

                    csTbl.CartID = cartQuery.First().CartID;
                    csTbl.ShoeID = shoeID;
                    csTbl.Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(quantityDdl.Text);

                    db.CartShoeTbls.InsertOnSubmit(csTbl);
                    db.SubmitChanges();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                cartTbl.CustomerID = cusID;
                cartTbl.TotalPrice = totalPrice;

                db.CartTbls.InsertOnSubmit(cartTbl);

                csTbl.CartID = cartTbl.CartID;
                csTbl.ShoeID = shoeID;
                csTbl.Quantity = quantity;

                db.CartShoeTbls.InsertOnSubmit(csTbl);

                db.SubmitChanges();
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Please login before you start to shopping !');</script>");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This one function is doing a lot of different things, including *four* separate calls to update the database.  Which one isn't working?

Comment: @David Check the marked line with comment //UPDATE LINE

Comment: And where do you add `cartTbl` to the database?  It looks like that only happens in an `else` branch.  So if the observed problem is in the `if` branch then clearly the `else` branch is never executed.

Comment: It is not about if else conditions. The other process in the else condition works properly.

Comment: Then, again, where do you add `cartTbl` to the database?  The line you've marked is where you change a property on `cartTbl`.  But if that object isn't in the database then what do you expect to be updating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cartTbl` is never set to any value that belongs to the database. It's the `new` cartTbl you created and it's not in the database. You need to change something that's *in* the database to update the database.

Comment: Please also refer to the msdn topic about update entities by linq2sql http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399339(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @nvoigt I have declared database context at the top of the method. Sorry i have forgotten to add it

Comment: It's not about the context. You have never assigned `cartTbl` to anything but a new object. What line in your database is it supposed to update?

Comment: @nvoigt cartTbl.TotalPrice = currentTotal;  //UPDATE LINE. It is this line.

Comment: No this line sets current total. But current total of what? You never assigned `cartTbl` some line from your database. Where is your line that says `cartTbl = databaseQueryResult;` ?

Comment: @Tartar: You're really not listening.  That line of code isn't updating the database because that line of code *doesn't update anything in the database*.  It just sets a property on an object in code.  Objects in code aren't a database.  In order to update data in the database, you need to update data that's *in the database*.

Comment: I got it, it should be something like this `cartQuery.First().TotalPrice = currentTotal;`